# How can I alert a text when an option is selected in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a selectbox...

```
 <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="color" id="color">
    <option value="red" selected>red</option>
    <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

... and I want to alert a text, when the option `green` is selected.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($( "#color option:selected" ).val()=='green'){
    alert("green");}
});
</script>
```

But my code is not working and I do not have any idea why...

Comment: add onchagne for select element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind this to some event like `change()` first to work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#color').change(function () {
        if (this.value == 'green') {
            alert("green");
        }
    });
});
```

[**`FIDDLE DEMO`**](http://jsfiddle.net/palash/9Lbt677c/)

Your code will only work if you set the `green` option as selected on load like

```
<option value="green" selected>green</option>
```

Currently it is set to red, hence it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to trigger your code when you change value of your `<select>`, like so:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#color').on('change', function() {

        if($(this).find('option:selected').val() == 'green') {
            alert('green');
        }

    });
});
```